# adding new line in Cordova code

Tags: android, html, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to add new line in Cordova code but unfortunately I did not get it
this is my code

```html
<!-- share_link -->
<div dir="rtl" class="item">
<button run-social-sharing message="{{**genpost.title.rendered+genpost.link+'More text Here'}**}" class="button button-small ion-android-share-alt button-outline button-positive icon-left">Share</button>
</div>
<!-- ./share_link -->
```

how can I add new line after title and link

I tried this

```html
{{genpost.title.rendered <br/> +genpost.link<br/> +'More text Here'}}
```

but it does not  work

Comment: Have you tried '/n' ?

Comment: yes I tried it same issue